# What should I enter in Debug user and Release User in android export section in Godot?

Tags: godot

I just want to export to android.
[image]

I have tried by adding my name, I got install error.

Comment: What does the doc say [Exporting for Google Play Store](https://github.com/godotengine/godot-docs/blob/8d7e85a26a1b0f5913c43e5c510331551a8c80b5/getting_started/workflow/export/exporting_for_android.rst#exporting-for-google-play-store)?

Comment: It says "Release User: Replace with the key alias." I don't what is key alias

Comment: The top of the section has more details about this, and it has a link to Android's documentation, maybe what you are looking for is there.

Comment: If you feel like you're lost with what you read in the documentation, then please edit the question and ask about it. Giving the most details in the question post will potentially help more future users visiting this page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create your keystore, you set an alias. Taking the example of the debugkeystore from the [documentation](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/getting_started/workflow/export/exporting_for_android.html):

```
keytool -keyalg RSA -genkeypair -alias androiddebugkey -keypass android -keystore debug.keystore -storepass android -dname "CN=Android Debug,O=Android,C=US" -validity 9999
```

The alias is `androiddebugkey` (set with `-alias`. That is what you should put as Debug User. Whatever you wrote for `-alias` when you generated your release keystore is what you should put for Release User.

---

If you forgot you alias but still have your password, you can run

```
keytool -list -keystore <name of keystore file>
```

The keytool will ask for the password. Once entered it will list the entries on the keystore. There should be one entry. The alias is name of the entry. *And that is what you put as user in Godot.*